# What Python library can help visualize/render a 4d (coordinates+position) matrix?

Tags: python, visualization

I'm seeking the alternative to a software called 3d doctor which can transform a stack of 2d images (step 1 and 2 in the figure below) into a 3d image with good rendering effect (step 3). Is there a package in python that can do the same thing? Thanks for any advice!
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what your looking for:

http://www.slicer.org/slicerWiki/index.php/Slicer4:Python

> A software platform for the analysis (including registration and interactive segmentation) and visualization (including volume rendering) of medical images and for research in image guided therapy.